# what is difference between two words, 'continual' and 'continuous'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Can you explain difference of these two words and give me some example sentences showing difference well?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/continual-or-continuous) on Oxford Dictionaries. There's a pretty good explanation:

> There is some overlap in meaning between continuous and continual, but the two words are not wholly synonymous. Both can mean roughly ‘without interruption’, for example:
>
> *a long and continual war*
>
> *five years of continuous warfare*
>
> However, continuous is much more prominent in this sense and, unlike
>   continual, can be used to refer to space as well as time, as in 'the
>   development forms a continuous line along the coast'. Continual, on
>   the other hand, typically means ‘happening frequently, with intervals
>   between’, as in 'the bus service has been disrupted by continual
>   breakdowns'. Overall, continuous occurs much more frequently than
>   continual (almost five times more often in the Oxford English Corpus).

To put it simply, "continuous" usually means running start to finish with nothing in between, while "continual" means frequently but with interruptions.